# What is in my meadow flowers seed mix?

Tags: identification, seeds

I was given a bag of seeds that are supposed to become "meadow plants", but it wasn't said what plants exactly.

Can you guess what plants some of these seeds originate from? I would like to know the origin for at least couple of them...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can recognize only Calendula officinalis and Centaurea cyanus. I hope you will get a more complete list. And the perfectly round seed looks very familiar, but I don't remeber what it is.

Comment: That's a tough question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The curly ones are Calendula
- I think some of the teensy tiny ones might be Poppies and/or foxglove but I'm not 100% sure (I'm basing the foxglove on a suggestion from Google that foxgloves are often in meadowflower mixes and there are similar looking seeds there)
- The ones that look like mini-paintbrushes are Cornflowers. (They remind me of Marigolds but Marigolds have longer "handles" on their paintbrushes).
- The ones that look like small black sesame-seeds may be Columbine Seeds
- I think the ones that look a bit like cumin seeds are OxEye daisies (there may be a second kind of Daisy in there too but I'm not sure)
- You may have some Lupine but it is hard to tell.
- 90% sure you have some Echinacea in there
- Maybe some Sweet William (do you have something looking like large-squished-black-sesame-seeds? I think so but the degree of "squished-ness" is hard to see.)
- The ones that look like Flax seeds are probably flax seeds (Blue Flax?)

Some of the larger rounder ones look really familiar but I cannot place them unfortunately :(

If you know what "area" the seeds are intended for (Australia? Southern USA? Dry places? Wet places? Shade? Sun?) it may help you to find a commercial pack of wildflower seeds for the same location and cross-check seed shapes :)